# Email Format issue in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

In this Scenario the user register from website and he get Welcome Email from ExactTarget,if any one of the user register through webpage and Email as **Email : test@t.com** ,and store the user record in salesforce. If i give like the email format as after **@ symbol((t)one letter)** the Exact Target throws the Status Message as **Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers..** If i use the Email format as **Email : test@tt.com** it works and the StatusMessage as Success..Is there any Email format restirction in ExactTarget one letter adding after the @ symbol?

Thanks
Venkatsforce

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening.  At the time of send, ET is performing validation on the domain.  And indeed, if you type t.com in your browser you go nowhere.  But, tt.com is an actual domain, which will cause it to pass validation.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Timothy, when am directly login to ExactTarget and send some test mail to this email id "test@t.com", it shows the notification as the Email is successfully sent it doesn't check any validation ,But when i am using this emailid on salesforce to send welcome email through ET it throws the error message as "Status Message as Unable to queue Triggered Send request. There are no valid subscribers.. "

Comment: Are you using test send?  I don't believe the "rules" are enforced on test send.  My hunch is that if you put test@t.com through a list, it wouldn't go.

Comment: Yes, @Timothy i am using test send in ET it doesn't check any validation for the email-id(test@t.com)